# Matplotlib Inset Axes modify the rectange connectors

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to change the inset zoom rectangle to not be a rectangle but just two lines. IE I obtain the image on the left but want the one one the right. [image]

I've tried a few things around modifying the rectangular draw. But I think I can't get it to just draw only a portion. I would really prefer not to manually just set the rectangle to 0 and then draw the lines, but I'm thinking that is most likely what I will need to do. Is there a better way?

Comment: Could you add a simple, minimal reproducible code example that creates at least the image at the left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Axes.indicate_axes_zoom` returns the Rectangle object:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)**(1/2))

axins = ax.inset_axes([0.6, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2])
axins.plot(np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)**(1/2))
axins.set_xlim([20, 60])
axins.set_ylim([1, 2.5])
rect, lines = ax.indicate_inset_zoom(axins)
rect.set_edgecolor('none')
```

For what it is worth, I'm not clear *why* you want this, but...

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I think it could look cleaner without a big box for a portion of just a 1d line. (What I do is set ylim to be on the lines at those points so it exactly matches)